# Low level XML stream writer in Go?

Tags: xml, go

I am looking for a simple (low level) XML Writer in Go, comparable with Java's javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter so I can write code like

```
writer := ...
writer.StartDocument()
writer.StartElement("p")
writer.CData("Some sample text")
writer.EndElement()
...
```

Is this supported by a public library or is there a better way to do it in idiomatic Go?

Comment: Have you try this link https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Projects

Comment: No. Found https://github.com/maxymania/gostax there. Will take a closer look. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Please answer the question yourself if `gostax` helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Golang actually has that as a built in package. http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml

There is an example here http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#example_Encoder but it isn't exactly isn't what you are looking for.
I've never used the stream writer you mentioned or any in general so I'm not sure if this fits the bill but I feel like you could easily wrap this to look like the solution you proposed. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the [XML encoding standard library](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml) (as Steven mentioned).

[Code Example](https://play.golang.org/p/-NA-paYY1vf):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    enc := xml.NewEncoder(&buf)
    enc.EncodeToken(xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "p"}})
    enc.EncodeToken(xml.CharData([]byte("Some sample text")))
    enc.EncodeToken(xml.EndElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "p"}})
    enc.Flush()
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

Output:

```
<p>Some sample text</p>
```

**NOTE:** Both `EncodeToken()` and `Flush()` return the `error` type and these should be checked before proceeding. I left this out in the example for brevity.

Also, if using `Encode()` or `EncodeElement()`, `Flush()` is called for you. You only need to call it explicitly when using `EncodeToken()`. See the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Encoder.EncodeToken) for full details.